How to redirect After login page to Google App Script Addon(Google Doc)?
I Want to add Auth2 into my Google Docs Addon I am opening a new window from my addon now the issue that I am facing is redirecting back to addon for redirectUri I am using https://script.google.com/macros/s/Script_ID/exec from project settings but I redirected to this I am getting this error

Google Docs encountered an error. Please try reloading this page, or coming back to it in a few minutes.
To learn more about the Google Docs editors, please visit our help centre.
We're sorry for the inconvenience.

The Google Docs Team


error image
How can I redirect to my addon?
here's an example of what I am doing
code.gs file function
function getAuthorizationUrl() {
  var a = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
  
  // Your app's Client ID from Azure Portal
  var clientId = "client_id"; 
  
  // The correct callback URL after user authorization
  var redirectUri = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/Script_Id/exec";
  
  // Scopes you are requesting access to (Microsoft Graph API scopes)
  var scope = "user.read mail.send openid profile email offline_access";
  
  // State and nonce for security
  var state = "12345"; 
  var nonce = "678910";

  // Assemble the full authorization URL
  var authUrl = a + "?client_id=" + clientId +
                "&response_type=code" + // Requesting an authorization code
                "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(redirectUri) + // The new redirect URL
                "&scope=" + encodeURIComponent(scope) +
                "&response_mode=fragment" +
                "&state=" + state +
                "&nonce=" + nonce;

  return authUrl;
} 

// Function to handle the callback and exchange the authorization code for an access token
function doGet(e) {
  var code = e.parameter.code; // Get the authorization code from the query parameters

  if (code) {
    // Proceed to exchange the authorization code for an access token
    // You can call a function to exchange the code for tokens and continue the flow
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Authorization complete! You can close this window.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Error: Authorization failed or no code returned.');
  }
}

html file code
<button onclick="login()">Sign in with OAuth</button>

<script>

 function login() {
        // Get the OAuth URL from the server
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(authUrl) {
          // Open the OAuth dialog in a new window
          window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'width=600,height=600');
        }).getAuthorizationUrl();
      }
</script>


Please add a [mcve].

If the project isn't deployed as webapp with relevant html code, the end point should be https://script.google.com/macros/s/Script_ID/callback

Hi @TheMaster I am using test deployment and type is Google Workspace Add-on 

Maybe you could get some idea here: Google Forum

@4thAnd No bro this wasn't helpful thanks!

Hi @TheMaster please take a look I added an example what I am doing

You would need a actual deployment(not test) and the  actual deployment url(not the script id) as the redirect uri.
